# Pass event through classes C#

Tags: c#, wpf, class, events

I have a first class that raises an event when some changes occur:

```
public class MyFirstClass {
    public event EventHandler ChangesHappened;

    public MyFirstClass() {

    }

    public void MyMethod() {
        //Thing happened

        ChangesHappened?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

I also have a second class that have a list of FirstClass:

```
public class MySecondClass {
    private List<MyFirstClass> first;

    public MySecondClass() {
        foreach(var f in first) {
            first.Changed += (s, e) => {};
        }
    }
}
```

And last I have a WPF application with an instance of SecondClass. How can I handle the Changed event (FirstClass) from WPF? Should I create an event in SecondClass and raise it inside `first.Changed += (s, e) => { NewEvent(this, new EventArgs()); }` and then catch this in the WPF?

The objective is get the Changed event in the WPF application.

Comment: It would be great if you provided a [mcve] - your code doesn't compile and has to be fixed before the question can be answered.

Comment: My code doesn't compile because I've not written any line of code xD. I'm asking for the best way to accomplish the task because I don't know how to afford it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Enigmativity already mentioned: When you have a class, that has to manage other classes (bunch of MyFirstClass references) then you have to forward your events from sub class to manager class.

```
public class MySecondClass
{
    public event EventHandler Changed;
    private List<MyFirstClass> firstClassList;

    public MySecondClass()
    {
        firstClassList = new List<MyFirstClass>();
    }

    public void AddMyFirstClassList(List<MyFirstClass> firstClassList)
    {
        foreach (var firstClass in firstClassList)
            AddMyFirstClass(firstClass);
    }

    public void AddMyFirstClass(MyFirstClass firstClass)
    {
        // from sub class to manager class
        firstClass.Changed += firstClass_Changed;
        firstClassList.Add(firstClass);
    }

    private void firstClass_Changed(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Changed?.Invoke(sender, args);
    }

    public void RemoveMyFirstClass(MyFirstClass firstClass)
    {
        MyFirstClass.Remove -= firstClass_Changed;
        firstClassList.Remove(firstClass);
    }
}
```

Another option is to pass a callback function. You should avoid this, unless you need it explicity:

```
public class MyFirstClass
{
    EventHandler handler;

    public MyFirstClass(EventHandler handler)
    {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        handler?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}

public class MySecondClass
{
    private List<MyFirstClass> firstClassList;

    public MySecondClass()
    {
        firstClassList = new List<MyFirstClass>();
    }

    // you have instantiated your class and passed your callback function previously.
    public void AddMyFirstClass(MyFirstClass firstClass)
    {
        firstClassList.Add(firstClass);
    }

    // for demonstrating the instantiation.
    public void AddMyFirstClass(EventHandler handler)
    {
        firstClassList.Add(new MyFirstClass(handler));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that this is the simplest answer:

```
public class MySecondClass
{
    public event EventHandler ChangesHappened;
    private List<MyFirstClass> first;

    public MySecondClass()
    {
        foreach (var f in first)
        {
            f.ChangesHappened += (s, e) => ChangesHappened?.Invoke(s, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the first solution I've thought. Let's wait for other answers. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use Microsoft's Reactive Framework which lets you pass events (well observables) around as first-class language citizens.

You could do this:

```
void Main()
{
    var msc = new MySecondClass();

    msc.Changes.Subscribe(ep =>
    {
        /* Do stuff with
            ep.Sender
            ep.EventArgs
                from the `MyFirstClass` instances
        */
    });
}

public class MyFirstClass
{
    public event EventHandler ChangesHappened;
    public IObservable<EventPattern<EventArgs>> Changes;

    public MyFirstClass()
    {
        this.Changes = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventHandler, EventArgs>(
            h => this.ChangesHappened += h, h => this.ChangesHappened += h);
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        ChangesHappened?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}

public class MySecondClass
{
    public IObservable<EventPattern<EventArgs>> Changes;

    private List<MyFirstClass> first = new List<MyFirstClass>();

    public MySecondClass()
    {
        this.Changes = first.Select(f => f.Changes).Merge();
    }
}
```